# tag meta share whatsapp

Tags: html5, laravel-5, seo, html-meta-tag

Olá pessoal estou tentando desenvolvendo uma aplicação e preciso de um botão para compartilhar um link via whatsapp, ele até compartilha mas as tags  não estão sendo carregadas por causa do subdominio!

Exemplo:

A Url abaixo não carrega as tags

https://admin.megavarejo.com.br/loja/11/produto/27

Já está carrega

https://megavarejo.com.br/loja/11/produto/27

Por causa do subdominio gerado para meus usúarios as imagens não estão indo, existe uma solução para isso? 
Gratidão!

Comment: Já tentou colocando o caminho absoluto da imagem?

Comment: já sim não deu certo! só funciona se a url enviada para a pessoa for sem sub domínio!